# How to view git checkout tags history?

Tags: git

Is there a log of all previous git pulls or tag checkouts for a git repo? We use a git checkout tags/ to update our live site, but we wanted to go back and see when all we did updates, so I'm trying to see if there is a way to check the history for git checkout tags/ command.

Answer (score 11):

`git reflog` shows the previous positions of `HEAD`.

Comment: This seems close, but it's missing the dates

Answer (score 9):

The reflog is probably the best place to see this type of information.

To show dates in the reflog output run this command:

```
git reflog --date=iso
```

Every time a tip of branch is updated (a commit, rebase, reset, etc) an entry is added to the reflog.

These entries can be used just like any other ref, meaning you can view them, revert back to them, diff them, etc.

For example, let's say you were doing a rebase and "lost" a commit. You could simply do a "git reflog" and find the identifier of the lost commit and then cherry-pick it back like this:

```
git reflog | grep commit # find the lost commit
git cherry-pick HEAD@{4}
```

Some good links:

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog

http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html

Note that the entries in the reflog will stay there for around 30 days before they are garbage collected by Git. This is configurable.

Comment: Does it have the date associated with each entry?

Comment: yep, next to each entry is something like this: "(x days ago)" EDIT: see later comment to show dates

Comment: I must be on a different version then, because I'm not seeing it. I'm on 1.7.10.4.

Comment: You can also do a "git show _id_" to get more information, such as author

Comment: oh, sorry...yes, by default it doesn't show the dates...do this: git reflog --date=iso